# How do i use while loop with a list of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to loop between the choices that user has given as input and the choices are stored as variables,

```
A = "A"
S = "S"
D = "D"
F = "F"
action_input = input("\n ")
action_input1 = action_input.title()
while (action_input1 not in [A, S, D, F]) :
    if action_input1 == A :
        print("\n Required Result is : " + str(Ac))
    elif action_input1 == S :
        print("\n Required Result is : " + str(Sc))
    elif action_input1 == D :
        print("\n Required Result is : " + str(Dc))
    elif action_input1 == F :
        print("\n Required Result is : " + str(Fc))
    else :
        print("\n Please enter from the choices given above")
```

Comment: What is `Ac` et. al?

Comment: Ac, Sc, Dc, Fc they are just variable storing some other value

Comment: While I shall be nice to first time users, I also want to be honest. I guess you get a lot of downvotes, because your code looks really messy. It shows a real lack of understanding Python. Maybe you want to do some tutorials first, before you write your own program.

Comment: yeah I'm new to python but I didn't get any tutorials on using while loops on a list of variables having different values , is there an another way of doing it ?  I just want user to type only from the four options and if any user types a choice except the four options it should prompt them and the user input should occur again!, im trying my best to follow the Zen of python and I wrote the code with spaces in each line but IDK this code is Being displayed this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask for input inside a `while True` loop and then `break` out of it when a valid input is given:

```
action_map = {
    "A": str(Ac),
    "S": str(Sc),
    "D": str(Dc),
    "F": str(Fc)
}

while True:
    action_input = input("\n ")
    action_input1 = action_input.title()
    if action_input1 in action_map:
        print("\n Required Result is : " + action_map[action_input1])
        break
    else :
        print("\n Please enter from the choices given above")
```